# Deploy a spring boot app as a Windows Service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

As part of my continuous integration process I need to deploy a spring boot application as a Windows service :(,  what would be the most recommended approach/tools to do it?
Spring boot documentation talks about  winsw:
https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw
but I don’t like its .NET dependencies, it may end complicating things.
Thanks

Comment: I think using winsw is the way to go.

Comment: Did you end up using winsw? I'm started with apache-commons-daemon, but it seems like it doesn't work with spring boot so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the other available java service wrappers

- [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)
- [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/)

YAJSW is easy to install and doesn't have any .NET dependencies.

Comment: thanks @MarcNuri I'm using YAJSW , not sure if is the best but is working fine